# Detailed description of all SCC's in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, okd

Is there any documentation page, source code, config file that has the details of all SCC's and not just the Restricted (which is used as example in every bit of documentation)?

And I don't have a running OpenShift instance to inquire this from the commandline.

Here's what i mean by detailed:

https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#examining-a-security-context-constraints-object

Answer (score 0):

Here is the design proposal of [security-context-constraints](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/proposals/security-context-constraints.md)

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what i was looking for but very useful

Comment: your welcome:) unforutanatly, I was not able find myself relvenent details on docs. the best choice is to use `oc explain scc.spec`